# How do I do this in Python (File Manipulation)?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a bunch of HTML files in HTML folder. Those HTML files have unicode characters which I solved by using `filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line)`. Now how do I write the changes back to the original file? What is the best way of doing it? Each HTML file is of 30 kb in size.

```
  1 import os, string
  2 
  3 for file in os.listdir("HTML/"):
  4     print file
  5     myfile = open('HTML/' + file)
  6     fileList = myfile.readlines()
  9     for line in fileList:
 10         #print line
 11         line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line)
 12     myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module. It allows you to read and write to the same file in place:

```
import fileinput,sys,os
files=[os.path.join('HTML',filename) for filename in os.listdir("HTML/")]
for line in fileinput.input(files, inplace=True):    
    line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: fileinput redirects sys.stdout to the file being operated upon.

Comment: I tried this code (also have to import string, no biggie). All I have is a blank htm file at the end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My bad, this code works. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

At first I didn't understand what @~unutbu was getting at, but after reading the documentation for `fileinput` module I found this, which I hadn't seen before (emphasis mine):

> Optional in-place filtering: if the
>   keyword argument inplace=1 is passed
>   to fileinput.input() or to the
>   FileInput constructor, the file is
>   moved to a backup file and **standard
>   output is directed to the input file**
>   (if a file of the same name as the
>   backup file already exists, it will be
>   replaced silently). This makes it
>   possible to write a filter that
>   rewrites its input file in place. If
>   the backup parameter is given
>   (typically as backup='.'), it specifies the
>   extension for the backup file, and the
>   backup file remains around; by
>   default, the extension is '.bak' and
>   it is deleted when the output file is
>   closed. In-place filtering is disabled
>   when standard input is read.

So I think his answer is best, and this explains why.

Comment: Keep appending the lines? I don't want to lose any formatting. How do I do it? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Linux; support on other operative systems is iffy (see below).

```
import os, string

for file in os.listdir("HTML/"):
    print file
    myfile = open('HTML/' + file)
    fileList = myfile.readlines()
    for pos, line in enumerate(fileList):
        line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line) # see note 1
        fileList[pos] = line                                 
    myfile.close()
    myfile = open('HTML/' + file, "wz") # see note 2
    myfile.write("\n".join(fileList))
```

**Note 1.** Simply assigning to `line` does not change `fileList`. Variables really are labels (references) onto objects: assigning to a label changes the object the label is attached to. That line creates a list which is then assigned

**Note 2.** The "wz" file mode empties the file on opening (it should be the equivalent of the `O_TRUNC` flag when passed to [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) ). It might not be available on platforms other than Linux.